# Spring boot application.properties hibernate.generate_statistics

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

After following various examples and reading the spring boot documentation I'm still unable to enable hibernate statistics. I'm setting the property in the application.properties file. Running the spring boot application via a integration test or `Application.java` produces no stats.

My `application.properties` file.

```
    spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    spring.datasource.username = postgres
    spring.datasource.password = password

    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
    spring.datasource.platform=postgres

    spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
    spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true

    logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE
    logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=TRACE

    logging.file=transaction-app.log
```

logback-spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

And my integration test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SqlMappingTest {

    @Autowired
    PlanService planService;

    @org.junit.Test
    public void findAll() {
        List<Plan> plans = planService.findAll();
        Assert.assertEquals(1, plans.size());

    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if the below is correct, but got it working.
I'm forcing the properties onto my `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` with construction.

DatabaseConfig snippet:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public class DatabaseConfig extends HikariConfig {

        @Autowired
        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, Environment env) {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

            entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);

            // Classpath scanning of @Component, @Service, etc annotated class
            entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.test"});

            // Vendor adapter
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

            Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql",
                    env.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql")
            );

            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql",
                    env.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql")
            );
            jpaProperties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics",
                    env.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics")
            );

            entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
            return entityManagerFactory;
        }
    }
```

After the config

```
2017-03-16 11:41:02.881 DEBUG 7884 --- [main] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000117: HQL: select up from UserPlan up, time: 48ms, rows: 1
2017-03-16 11:41:02.885  INFO 7884 --- [main] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
    939077 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    2848386 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    12205063 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    18693 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

Comment: Just for completenes, all the settings from different sources influencing hibernate can be accessed via the classpath "org.hibernate.cfg.Environment."

Answer (score 18):

It works for me (using Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE).

a) In file application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

b) Ensure runtime debug level for 'org.hibernate.stat' is at least DEBUG:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"configuredLevel": "DEBUG"}' http://localhost:8080/actuator/loggers/org.hibernate.stat
```

c) Check in log something like:

```
2019-07-03 21:27:27.739 DEBUG 11797 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.stat.internal.StatisticsImpl         : HHH000117: HQL: select count(*) from AppRequest x WHERE x.uuid = :uuid, time: 1ms, rows: 1
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this. I looked at half a dozen answers before I realized I needed spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics and not just hibernate.generate_statistics in my app.properties file.

Answer (score 3):

Define property `hibernate.generate_statistics=true` in `hibernate.properties` file.

Answer (score 1):

Running the application with `-Dhibernate.generate_statistics=true` did it for me.